Are all real uniformly bounded matrices orthogonal?
Inspired by a closed question, let $A$ be an integer coefficient matrix such that $\exists B$ and for $i \in \mathbb{N\setminus\{0\}}, \ |a| \leq B$ for all elements of $A^i$. This condition is apparently named "Uniform boundedness of a matrix". From this it follows due to the finity of matrices which have all entries bound that there exists $n > 0$ such that $A^n = I$.
I studied this question a bit more and before discovering/using the fact $A^n = I$, we get from the bound with Hadamard's inequality that $\mathrm{det(A)} = 1$ for all real matrices. I then started playing around with examples of integer matrices with $\mathrm{det(A)} = 1$  and I noticed that it seemed that the singular values of $A$ determine if it satisfies the uniform boundedness condition. For me it seemed that we must have $\Sigma = I$. Geometrically I'm thinking: if the largest singular value in $\Sigma$ is larger than $1$, we can apply $A$ ad nauseam to a vector $\bar{v}$, only increasing the length and the condition $A^n = I$ would never be satisfied. Therefore, we need the largest singular value to be $1$.
Because $\mathrm{det(A)} = 1$ and assuming the largest value in $\Sigma$ is $1$, we would get that all values are $1$. This implies that $A$ is orthogonal, since the SVD is $U\Sigma V^T =UIV^T = UV^T$, in other words, a product of orthogonal matrices. Right now I'm lacking a rigorous step to show that the boundedness condition implies that $\Sigma = I$.
Question: are all integer-coefficient uniformly bounded matrices orthogonal and is this only true for integers or is it also true for reals?

Counterexample: $\pmatrix{1&1\ 0&-1}^2=I$. More generally, pick a random $n\times n$ unimodular matrix $P$. Let $C$ be the permutation matrix for a left shift (i.e., the companion matrix for $x^n-1$. More often than not, $A=PCP^{-1}$ is not orthogonal.

It seems that I've rushed into conclusions because we can have $det(A) = -1$ as well. Is there a counterexample if we force $det(A) = 1$?

Yes, such as $A=\pmatrix{-1&1&0\ 0&-1&1\ 2&-3&2}$.

If $n$ is not required to the the size of $A$, you may also consider the counterexample $A=\pmatrix{0&-1\ 1&-1}$ such that $A^3=I_2$ and $\det(A)=1$. Clearly $A$ is not orthogonal because its second column is not a unit vector.
